# JdbcCursorItemReader - Stored Procedure call

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Currently I am using JdbcCursorItemReader and FlatFileItemWriter in a job step.

Due to performance issue we have to use stored procedure.

Is there a way to make a call to stored proc in Spring Batch 2.0.. RELEASE?

```
<bean id="jdbcCursorItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="sql"
value="SELECT X,Y,Z 
FROM V_VIEW "/>
<property name="mapper">
<bean class="com.mapping.SomeMapper"/>
</property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFil eItemWriter" id="flatFileItemWriter">
<property name="resource" ref="resource"/>
<property name="fieldSetCreator">
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping .PassThroughFieldSetMapper"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

... Other config
how to write a custom database reader wih callable statement... 
Sample code is appreciated..  Thank You,.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `StoredProceedureItemReader` that is built just for this use case.  You can read more about it in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/StoredProcedureItemReader.html

Comment: It's available in Spring Batch 2.1 which should be a non breaking upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I could find my answer:

```
<bean id="jdbcCursorItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="sql" value="Call schema.StoredProcName"/>
<property name="mapper">
<bean class="com.mapping.SomeMapper"/>
</property>
</bean>
```